# Реализовать последовательность

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Мне нужно реализовать последовательность https://oeis.org/A323119 на С++, но конкретных формул нет. Как это сделать ?

Comment: В смысле нет? В строке `FORMULA` указано: a(n) = c * d^n, где d = 1.8392867552141611325518525646532866..., c = 0.618419922319392550945330438071061626105588310617942936855358363357952137... В коде это будет примерно в виде `for (unsigned i = 1; i < N; i++) {std::cout << (0.61841992231939255094533043807106162610558831061794293685535836335795213 * std::pow(1.8392867552141611325518525646532866, (double)i)) << std::endl;}`

Comment: Там пишет a(n) ~ c * d^n. Формула дает значение не совсем правильное, проверял

Answer (score 0):

Раз точной формулы нет, то от Вас требуется рассчитать значения самостоятельно.

Приведу намеренно примитивный способ на Python - генерация всех возможных композиций числа на слагаемые в диапазоне k..k+2 с  проверкой, что в композиции  действительно есть конечные значения диапазона

```
def comp2_int(n, mn, mx, hasmn, hasmx):
    if n == 0 and hasmn and hasmx:
        return 1
    if n < 0:
        return 0
    res = 0
    for i in range(mn, mx + 1):
        res += comp2_int(n - i, mn, mx, (i == mn) or hasmn, (i == mx) or hasmx)
    return res

def comp2(n):
    res = 0
    for k in range(1, n-1):
        res += comp2_int(n, k, k+2, False, False)
    return res

for m in range(15):
    print(m, comp2(m))

3 0
4 2
5 3
6 12
7 20
8 49
9 95
10 188
11 366
12 714
13 1347
14 2565
```

Более эффективно может быть использовать генерацию наборов с невозрастающими слагаемыми (например, `5=3+1+1`), затем умножать на количество перестановок с повторениями (в данном случае `3=3!(2!1!)`), но ещё лучше - какой-либо вид динамического программирования, когда мы повторно используем вычисленные для некоторого набора `(n, min, max)` *(причём max-min может быть не только 2, но и 0 и 1)* результаты позже.

Ну это уже для Вас упражнение.